# CloudKit public container access when user is logged in but iCloud Drive is disabled

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have an app that uses CloudKit for the backend, and it works fine getting data when the user is not logged in, or if the user is logged in and iCloud Drive is enabled. However, if the **user is logged in** ***and*** **iCloud Drive is disabled**, I get an error on my CKQuery and the returned results are empty. The error is:

> "Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "Account doesn't have access to CloudKit account"

This behavior seems strange to me as users could be logged out and access data. Is it possible to get users public container data with iCloud Drive disabled?

Note: this is necessary because many people I know have Corporate MDM profiles installed that restrict iCloud Drive access, thereby killing the backend for my app.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this as well. I found under ios9 xcode 7 users that were not logged into iCloud could read but not write.

> For a running CloudKit app, a container’s public database is always
>   readable, even when the user is not signed in to their iCloud account
>   on the device. Saving records to the public database and accessing the
>   private database requires that the user be signed in

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/DesigningforCloudKit/DesigningforCloudKit.html

All my tests since ios10 and xcode 8 show that this is no longer the case and if you are not logged into iCloud you cannot read or write. I can't find any documentation to prove this, but running my app on a device with ios9 it works and on ios10 it doesn't.

Comment: I have been able to get data when not signed in on iOS 10, but on the device only and not in the simulator. In the simulator there appears to be some sort of bug. I also found out the hard way that Apple will not allow your app in the App Store if it requires iCloud login for core features.

Comment: I should also mention that write functionality has always required iCloud login

Comment: @EarlybirdAdam I haven't got it to work on an actual device at all with ios10. I have set my app to test if a user is logged in and either load data or display an alert to tell them to log in. So from the sounds of it that will get me rejected. Is there anything in particular you did to get it to read with users not logged in?

Comment: @EarlybirdAdam I have just retested everything and without being logged into icloud the fetch function always returns 0

Comment: Check to make sure you've set your CloudKit security preferences correctly. Go to the dashboard, select the record type, and click the security drop down. Make sure the "World - Read" checkbox is checked as well as the "Public-Read" checkbox

Comment: Also, don't forget which environment you're in, production vs development when you make the security changes